# Zend Framework: Zend_Form is not including 'name' attribute in form tag

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have following class for a form:

```
class Application_Form_ContactForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
      $this->setName('contact_us');
     /* 
       I have also used follwing statements (one by one) to set name attribute 
       // $this->setAttrib('name', 'myForm-name');
       // $this->setAttribs(array('name' => 'frm', 'id' => 'frmlogin')); 
     */
    }
}
```

When I run this form, I get follwoing html code:

```
<form id="contact_us" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post"><dl class="zend_form">
```

The above mentioned html code doesn't show 'name' attribute of the form html tag.

Can some one guide me in this regards, how to rectify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "name" attribute is allowed in HTML4 but has been deprecated in XHTML1.0. The HTML specification does not allow for a "name" attribute for forms. [Check Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp).

Zend Framework is just following the rules.

But why do you need a name is form anyway? Almost everything can be done using class and id.

But, if you really need it that bad try setting a ID first and then the name, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to set focus for a text input of a form field. Without specifying the 'name' attribute, the OnLoad focus does NOT work. If 'name' is deprecated, there must be another way  to support this focus(). A simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body OnLoad="document.InputForm.CMD.focus();">
       <div><b>Focus Test</b></div>
       <form ID="InputForm" method="post" action="">
           <input type="text" name="CMD" id="CMD" value="" size="50" />
           <input type="submit" name="OK" id="OK" value="OK" />
       </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update: Tracking down to Zend Framework source, I found down that Zend is checking for the doctype if it is 'Strict' or not. So the solution is simple:
    Edit application.ini and change the doctype line:
        resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
    to
        resources.view.doctype = "XHTML5"
and the focus works OK.